# Rotating part of button when hovering over entire span

Tags: css

I'd like the chevron to rotate on hover over the entirety, not just when I'm hovering over itself. So in other words, when I hover over the word "About" I'd like the chevron to rotate too. Ideally i'd like the "About" to turn red on hover as well but that's secondary. Thank you for the help!

```
<div class="btn">About
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
</div>

.btn {
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 14px 28px;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn i {
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.btn i:hover {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `.btn:hover i` selector?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the `:hover` selector on `.btn` class.

It's also good to take a look at this pseudo selector as well `:focus-within` 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;  
}

.btn i {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: #000;
}

.btn:hover i {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn">About
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.btn:hover i` selector instead of `.btn i:hover`:

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn i {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.btn i:hover {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.btn-2:hover i {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn">Does not work
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
</button>

<button class="btn btn-2">Works
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
</button>
```

Also - you should use `button` instead of `div` for button elements.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for